# Only if col in table 1 time

Tags: mysql

I have this SQL

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.[3S Company A_S$Posted Invt_ Put-away Header] 
INNER JOIN dbo.[3S Company A_S$Posted Invt_ Put-away Line] ON dbo.[3S Company A_S$Posted Invt_ Put-away Header].No_ = dbo.[3S Company A_S$Posted Invt_ Put-away Line].No_ 
WHERE ([Posting Date] > '" & request.form("from") & "' AND [Posting Date] < '" & request.form("to") & "')
```

And it works like charm. But my output is not correct.

I only want my output, if dbo.[3S Company A_S$Posted Invt_ Put-away Line].[Item No_] in the table 1 time. If [item no_] is in the table more that one time, i don't want it.

How can i fix that?

Comment: try using count(variable) if(count=1) display.. implement it in query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of, this is not MySQL. It's SQL Server I guess? Please tag your questions with the appropriate tags in the future.

To answer your question, you'd have to add

```
GROUP BY dbo.[3S Company A_S$Posted Invt_ Put-away Line].[Item No_]
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
```

Short explanation: You can have aggregate functions in a query, like `SELECT MAX(price) FROM whatever;`. Such a query always returns one row, the one with the highest price. You can add a `GROUP BY` to get the highest price per dealer like this: `SELECT dealer, MAX(price) FROM whatever GROUP BY dealer;` When you have multiple dealers in your table, you get more rows. Now you can have a `HAVING` clause on top of that. The difference between `WHERE` and `HAVING` is, that `WHERE` is applied before `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` is applied after. So, to check if an entry is just one time in a table, you group by it and check if the number of rows for that group is 1. That's what the above does.

The problem now is, that a database can't decide which rows of a group to display, when there are more than one, so the rule is, that when you apply a `GROUP BY` clause, every column in the `SELECT` clause must either be specified in the `GROUP BY` clause or an aggregate function has to be applied on that column.

So you will have to adjust your `SELECT` clause, simply `SELECT * ...` with `GROUP BY` doesn't work.

Ram suggests to use `DISTINCT`. This does something completely different. It simply displays a row just one time when every column of the `SELECT` clause is the same for multiple rows. It does not filter rows, that are there multiple times, it just displays them once. There's no checking involved.

P.S.: Please make sure to sanitize your input for queries. I'm no programmer, but your query sure looks suspicious with this `'" & request.form("from") & "'`. Read about SQL injection attacks...
And another advice...You can use aliases for table names to make your queries look more pretty and having less to type.

Answer (score 0):

If it is the only column you want to display then it would be possible by using the `DISTINCT` keyword. But you are using * (displays the entire set of columns). SQL treats only row as a single entity. Hence if there is any difference in any of the column values, the entire row would be displayed again even if you use `DISTINCT`